# Pharmacist Database in Canada

Tags: data-request, medical, canada, drugs

Where would I be able to get some demographic and employment data for pharmacists in Canada? Much like this one:

http://www.cihi.ca/CIHI-ext-portal/internet/en/document/spending+and+health+workforce/workforce/other+providers/PDB_METADATA

I am still an undergraduate so I can't apply through their graduate program. And it costs way too much for independent university research.

As a non-gradudate student, one has to pay access fees to the database, at the following rates:

*Data request pricing
CIHI responds to data requests on a cost-recovery basis, as follows:
•$145/hour, for Canadian health care facilities, media (data requests only), governments, not-for-profit health agencies, universities (except for students through the Graduate Student Data Access Program), health professionals and researchers from the public sector (Price A clients)
•$290/hour for private commercial operations (including but not limited to software vendors and consultants), foreign clients (Price B clients) and others not qualifying for Price A*

Is there an alternate source?